# After common Typeorm query builder instance, where clause not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm, query-builder

I create QueryBuilder to fetch my relation data. So in my case, I need to validate some of my
get req params before the index. So in this case I created a common QueryBuilder instance like this.

```
// Common Get Query
      const result = await this.reservationRepo
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .leftJoinAndSelect('Reservation.userId', 'userId')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('Reservation.companyId', 'companyId')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('Reservation.petId', 'petId')
        .orderBy(`Reservation.${sortBy}`, order)
        .where('Reservation.isArchived = :isArchived', { isArchived: false });
```

and then I wrote my validation logic like this;

```
//Check req starts is cancelled and return canceled data (getting data from db)
  if (getPaginationParamDto.status === GetReservationTypes.CANCELLED) {
    if (type === GetReservationTypes.COMPANY) {
      result.where('Reservation.companyId = :companyId', { companyId: `${searchID}` });
    } else {
      result.where('Reservation.userId = :userId', { userId: `${searchID}` });
    }
    result.where('Reservation.status = :status', { status: getPaginationParamDto.status });
```

But the problem is my where

> isArchived: false

is not working.

```
.where('Reservation.isArchived = :isArchived', { isArchived: false });
```

**So in this case, I wrote my isArchived where Query
after my logics. (end of everything) after that, it's working. But my condition is not applied for that. So I really need your help with this case. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to TypeORM's documentation on [adding WHERE expressions](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#adding-where-expression):

> [...] If you use `.where` more than once you'll override all previous `WHERE` expressions.

So you need to revise your logic to use `.andWhere()` instead if you want to apply multiple WHERE clauses to your query.

Maybe something like:

```js
const result = await this.reservationRepo
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .leftJoinAndSelect("Reservation.userId", "userId")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("Reservation.companyId", "companyId")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("Reservation.petId", "petId")
  .orderBy(`Reservation.${sortBy}`, order)
  .where("Reservation.isArchived = :isArchived", { isArchived: false });

// [...]

if (getPaginationParamDto.status === GetReservationTypes.CANCELLED) {

  if (type === GetReservationTypes.COMPANY) {
    result.andWhere("Reservation.companyId = :companyId", { companyId: `${searchID}` });
  } else {
    result.andWhere("Reservation.userId = :userId", { userId: `${searchID}` });
  }

  result.andWhere("Reservation.status = :status", { status: getPaginationParamDto.status });

// [...]
```

However, you might want to remove the `await` on line 1 if you're trying to add these additional `WHERE` clauses BEFORE executing the query. Finish building the query before executing it.